# How to replace word without changing line length in VIM

Tags: vim

I have file:

```
word          some other word
```

(10 spaces after word)

I want to replace word without change line length

Example:

```
new word      some other word
```

(6 spaces after word)

Is it posible in vim?

I now only one solution `c` `l` `8` but I should know length of `new word` to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use <kbd>R</kbd> to enter Replace mode.  This allows you to type `new word` "over" `word` without modifying the amount of space.  The downside of this is if you wanted to replace a longer word with a shorter word you would have to "blank" out the extra characers from the old word.

See `:help R` and `:help gR` for more info.